# How to sort List<tuple<class1,class2>?

Tags: c#

basically I want to add to List of tuples containing different classes into List and then want to sort the objects based on class2.

```
var myList = new List<Tuple<class1, class2>>();
 myList.Add(new Tuple<class1, class2>(class1obj,class2obj));
```

How to sort the myList values based on a property in class 2??

Answer (score 3):

If you have the existing list and want to sort it, call the [`Sort()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx) method specifying the [`Comparison`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh.aspx) to use.  Then compare the second items in whatever appropriate manner.

e.g.,

```
var items = new List<Tuple<int, string>>
{
    Tuple.Create(1, "foo"),
    Tuple.Create(15, "bar"),
};
items.Sort((a, b) => a.Item2.CompareTo(b.Item2));
```

Comment: Of course, there are other overloads that could be used. This isn't your _only_ option.

Answer (score 2):

```
myList = myList.OrderBy(n => n.Item2.YourProperty).ToList();
```

will give you your result.

(needs to be `using System.Linq;`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var sortedList = myList.OrderBy(x => x.Item2.Property).ToList();
```

Where `Property` is the property you want to sort by.